# CorePlot vertical scrolling for horizontal bars

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I'm using core plot to graph a bunch of data with the ranges:

X: 0 to 200
Y: 0 to 35

I've made my bar graph render Horizontally but it will not scroll.

I have:

```
func setupSpace() {
    let plot = CPTBarPlot()
    plot.barsAreHorizontal = true
    plot.delegate = self
    plot.dataSource = self
    plot.barCornerRadius = 5.0
    plot.barWidth = 2.0
    plot.barOffset = 1.0
    self.hostedGraph?.addPlot(plot)
}

func reloadData() {
    let xMin = 0.0
    let yMin = 0.0
    let xMax = 200
    let yMax = 35.0

    let plotSpace = self.hostedGraph?.defaultPlotSpace as! CPTXYPlotSpace

    plotSpace.xRange = CPTPlotRange(locationDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(xMin), lengthDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(xMax - xMin))
    plotSpace.globalXRange = CPTPlotRange(locationDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(xMin), lengthDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(xMax - xMin))

    plotSpace.yRange = CPTPlotRange(locationDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(yMax), lengthDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(-(yMax - yMin) - 1))
    plotSpace.globalYRange = CPTPlotRange(locationDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(yMax), lengthDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(-(yMax - yMin) - 1))

    self.hostedGraph?.reloadData()
}
```

But my bars draw like:

### [image]

I need them to draw without overlapping and I need them to be able to scroll in the vertical direction.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the length of the `yRange` to only show some of the bars in the visible plot area. You will be able to scroll to see the other bars.

Comment: I did this. It still won't scroll the yRange. I have the yGlobalRange to 30 and the yRange to 15. Only 15 bars show but the others won't and it won't scroll.

Comment: Did you set `allowsUserInteraction` to `YES` on the plot space?

Comment: Yeah. I got it working. I was restricting scrolling when overriding `func plotSpace(space: CPTPlotSpace, willChangePlotRangeTo newRange: CPTPlotRange, forCoordinate coordinate: CPTCoordinate) -> CPTPlotRange?` I fixed it and now it scrolls.